# wp_list_categories link to first post of category instead of calling taxonomy template

Tags: posts, categories, links

I'm using wp_list_categories to give me a list of links to categories (no surprise there)

Is it possible to get Wordpress to link to the first post of a given category instead of calling the taxonomy template which displays links to all posts in that category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up resolving it by using this in the taxonomy template instead...

```
<?php
    /*
    Redirect To First Child
    */
    if (have_posts()) {
      while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        $pagekids = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID."&sort_column=menu_order");
        $firstchild = $pagekids[0];
        wp_redirect(get_permalink($firstchild->ID));
      }
    }
```

?>