# Taxonomy list links to first post in that term

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type of 'artworks' and a custom taxonomy of 'artists'.  On page-artists.php I have created a custom list of all the artists and would like to link each artist's name to the first post associated with that term instead of going to the term's page. This is my current code:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php 

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'artworks', // change this to the post type you registered
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'artists',
        'field' => 'id'
      )
    )
  );
 $first_cat_post = get_posts($args);

$terms = get_terms('artists', $args);

// list artists alphabetically by last name
$count = count($terms); $i=0;
if ($count > 0) {
    $term_list = '<ul class="artist-list">';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $i++;

        // group terms by first letter                      
        $this_char = strtoupper(substr($term->name,0,1));
        if ($this_char != $last_char) {
          $last_char = $this_char;
          $term_list .= '<li><h2>'.$last_char.'</h2></li>';
        } 

        $termid = 'artists_' . ($term->term_id);
        $termfirst = get_field('first_name', $termid);

        // link artist name with first work by that artist
        $term_list .= '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, $term->taxonomy ) . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">' . $termfirst . ' ' . $term->name . '</a></li>';     
    }
    $term_list .= '</ul>';
    echo $term_list;
}

?><?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Here is the [dev site](http://amocadev.dreamhosters.com/artists/). Right now the term list items are linking to that terms page, but it is a 404. [This Answer looks promising](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22390/wp-list-categories-link-to-first-post-of-category-instead-of-calling-taxonomy-te), but I do not know what template file to put the code in.  I tried putting this code:

```
<?php
/*
Redirect To First Child
*/
if (have_posts()) {
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    $pagekids = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID."&sort_column=menu_order");
    $firstchild = $pagekids[0];
    wp_redirect(get_permalink($firstchild->ID));
  }
}
```

?>

in taxonomy-artists.php, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// link artist name with first work by that artist
$term_list .= '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, $term->taxonomy ) . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">' . $termfirst . ' ' . $term->name . '</a></li><li>' . the_terms() . '</li>';
```

change the above lines to

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'artworks',
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'artists' => $term->slug,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
));
// link artist name with first work by that artist
$term_list .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $posts[0]->ID ) . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">' . $termfirst . ' ' . $term->name . '</a></li><li>' . the_terms() . '</li>';
```

This will change the link to the latest post. You will probably want to modify the "orderby" & "order" parameters in the code. The possible values are available here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

In your code you don't need the line `$first_cat_post = get_posts($args);`

Also please correct the parameters in the `$args`, see this page for reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to do.  I removed the follow parameter in the $args in the original question as it was not listed in codex. 'terms' => array($category->term_id)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `get_pages` is an appropriate use for this case, I believe `get_posts` is what you need. Also, `wp_redirect` won't work if its just thrown into your theme template file **IF** headers have already been sent. Its best executed from within your functions.php as in the example below.

We are hooking onto `template`_redirect which is the last action to fire before displaying presentation to the user (then comes get_header, etc...).

We then check that the query var is attempting to retrieve a term name which belongs to our taxonomy (in your case `artists`) and if that condition returns `true` we grab the first post, its permalink, then redirect the user to that first post.

### Solution: (to be placed in your functions.php file)

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'first_post');

function first_post(){
    global $wp_query;
    global $post;

    if ( $wp_query->query_vars['artists'] === get_query_var('artists') ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'artworks', // change this to the post type you registered
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'artists',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => get_query_var( 'artists' )
                )
            )
    );

    $first_post = get_posts($args);
    foreach($first_post as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
    wp_redirect(get_permalink($post->ID));
    exit;
    endforeach;

    }//end if-block conditional
}
```

The advantage of this method is that you get to keep your link structure appearance, example;

✔    `http://www.example.com/artists/michael-aakhus/`
✔    `http://www.example.com/artists/jane-abrams/`
            etc...

Instead of your links appearing as,

⨯   `http://www.example.com/artists/michael-aakhus/%postname%`
⨯  `http://www.example.com/artists/jane-abrams/%postname%`
            etc...

Until of course the user is redirected, then the address bar will show the appropriate URL with full post-name.

Comment: This solution also works, but I went with the answer that directly links the term list to the first post.